# Magento 2 Invoice Emails: Tax row alignment in subtotals

Tags: template, email-templates, invoice, order-totals, customer-emails

So I wanted to change the layout of my invoice emails, especially order totals. I wanted labels to align right.
I copied my totals.phtml file in my theme and added my styling.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * @var $block \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals
 * @see \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals
 */
?>
<?php foreach ($block->getTotals() as $_code => $_total) : ?>
    <?php if ($_total->getBlockName()) : ?>
        <?= $block->getChildHtml($_total->getBlockName(), false) ?>
    <?php else :?>
        <tr class="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_code) ?>">
            <th <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getLabelProperties() ?> scope="row" style="text-align: right !important; padding-right:20px">
                <?php if ($_total->getStrong()) : ?>
                    <strong><?= $block->escapeHtml($_total->getLabel()) ?></strong>
                <?php else : ?>
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml($_total->getLabel()) ?>
                <?php endif ?>
            </th>
            <td <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getValueProperties() ?> data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_total->getLabel()) ?>">
                <?php if ($_total->getStrong()) : ?>
                    <strong><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->formatValue($_total) ?></strong>
                <?php else : ?>
                    <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->formatValue($_total) ?>
                <?php endif?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach?>
```

It gave the desired stying changes except for TAX row in my order totals.
[image]

for Tax row I did some research and I found tax module in vendor so I copied tax.phtml from tax module tried making changes. But still the TAX label is there in the center. Can anyone tell me how can I change the alignment of tax field.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this tax label alignment issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable tax calculation for orders in the backend config
https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-configure-us-tax-magento-2.html